# dropdownmenu with image and form

Tags: jquery, python, css, django

UPDATE:

I edit my code to this:
Now seems like it post both the values (en , zh-tw ) to  `/i18n/setlang/`
I think it's because I have `for loop`

How can I edit??
Please help me thank you very much!!

```
<style>
#dropmenu {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    /*border: 2px solid purple;*/
    /*width: 200px;*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#dropmenu > ul { display: none; }
#dropmenu:hover > ul {display: block; background: #f9f9f9;  }
#dropmenu:hover > ul > li { padding: 5px;  }
#dropmenu:hover > ul > li:hover { background: white;}
#dropmenu:hover > ul > li:hover > a { color: red; }
</style>

<script  type="text/javascript">
    function selectdo(obj) {
                        str="/i18n/setlang/";
                        myform = document.getElementById('testform');
                        myform.method = "POST";
                        myform.action = str;
                        myform.submit();
                }
</script>    

<ul id="header">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="{% url 'core:maininfo' %}#firstPage">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="{% url 'core:maininfo' %}#secondPage">Note</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div id='dropmenu'>
            <img src="{% static 'img/lan.png' %}" />
            <ul>
                 {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                <form name="testform" id="testform" method='post'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
                <input name="language" type="hidden" value="{{ lang.0 }}"  id="lang"/>
                <li  value="{{ lang.0 }}" ><a href="#" onclick="selectdo(); return false;" > {{ lang.1 }}</a></li>
                 {% endfor %}
                 </form>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Original question:**

```
<ul id="header">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="{% url 'core:maininfo' %}#firstPage">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="{% url 'core:maininfo' %}#secondPage">Note</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="{% static 'img/lang.png' %}" />
    </li>
    <li>
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        <form name="testform" id="testform" method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select id="language" name="language" onchange="selectdo(this)">
            <option value="1" >{% trans "Languages" %}</option>
                {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
            <option value="{{ lang.0 }}" > {{ lang.1 }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
        </select>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have an select option for changing language.
And now  I want to merge the `<img src="{% static 'img/lang.png' %}" />` and the `<form name="testform" id="testform" method='post'>` part.
if the user click the image, it will jump languages(chinese and english) for user to choose like dropdown menu.
Please guide me how to do this,thank you!!

Comment: Could you clarify what the desired behavior is when someone clicks the image? Do you want to submit the form or change a dropdown value?

Comment: when it click the image(or hover it),it will show languages ( now I only have chinese and english ), when user click the languages's option value.I will use javascript to submit the form. So all I need is the image have dropdown menu function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's due to the for loop. It creates 2 `input` elements with the same id and the values are being set to `{{ lang.0 }}`, so when you post it posts both languages. You should have 1 `input` element which holds the value being posted.

Try editing your `ul` to place the input outside the loop as well as setting a parameter for the `onclick="selectdo();"`:

```
<ul>
     {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
    <form name="testform" id="testform" method='post'>
    <input name="language" type="hidden" id="lang"/>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}     
    <li  value="{{ lang.0 }}" ><a href="#" onclick="selectdo('{{ lang.0 }}'); return false;" > {{ lang.1 }}</a></li>
     {% endfor %}
     </form>
</ul>
```

And then modify the javascript function to set the input before posting:

```
function selectdo(obj) {
        var langInput = document.getElementById('lang');
        langInput.value = obj;

        str="/i18n/setlang/";
        myform = document.getElementById('testform');
        myform.method = "POST";
        myform.action = str;
        myform.submit();
}
```